# Discord bot pauses (doesn't respond to commands) while its processing other things

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a function which gets data from an external site. This takes about 2-5 seconds. During the time its getting data from the other site, the bot essentially doesn't respond to any commands until it has retrieved the external data.

```
import requests as req
@commands.command()
async def getdata(self, ctx):
    try:
        ses = req.Session()
        r = ses.get("https://stackoverflow.com") # this line takes about 2-5 seconds
    except:
        pass
    await ctx.send("Got the data")
```

How can I make the bot still get the data and perform the commands others are doing

Comment: You're looking for [concurrency](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrency.html), maybe [`aiohttp`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/).

Comment: @ForceBru you should make that an answer